# Blazor binding value to "input date" in one-way

Tags: c#, blazor

Since Blazor doesn't support stopping event propagation I need one-way binding for an input element with `type="date"` and with an `onchange` event handler.

Something like this:

```
<input type="date" value="@_endDate" format-value="yyyy-MM-dd" onchange="@EndDate_change"/>
```

But this doesn't work. The page contains datePicker but without any value.

"_endDate" is of type DateTime.

If I use Two-way binding then everything working fine.

```
<input type="date" bind="@_endDate" format-value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
```

Any idea why the first "input" doesn't work? Is there any mistake or is this a bug in blazor?
For plain text one-way binding with onchange event works without problems.

Edit1:
_endDate contains the current date and is set as DateTime.Now

```
protected void EndDate_change(UIChangeEventArgs endDateEvent)
{
    _endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(endDateEvent.Value);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: How do you set `_endDate` and what does `EndDate_change` do? If you [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding) binding is equivalent to setting the new value in the change event. You still have to set `_endDate` to *something* if you want it to be displayed

Comment: Please look at Edit1. I added it to question.

Comment: I can't repro this. The date shows (Chrome, Firefox, edge) but the event is not triggered from a date input. Latest Blazor, clientside.

Comment: Are you trying to change date value from javascript (datePicker) ? Then, maybe, you should to need [interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 15):

To keep both `@onchange=` and a one way `value=` use this

`value="@someDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"`

The trick is to format as a string `yyyy-MM-dd` to get one way binding from the value. Formatting differently or simply using the `DateTime` object fails to show the date inside the date selector.

Example:

`<input type="date" value="@knowledge.ActualShortTermDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" @onchange="@(async (e) => await updateDate(DateTime.Parse(e.Value.ToString())))" />`

Answer (score 3):

Since in blazor @bind-Value and @onchange cannot co exists as at now here is the best work around

```
<InputDate type="date" @bind-Value="@_endDate"/>
@code {
 private DateTime endDate;
public DateTime _endDate
{
    get { return endDate; }
    set
    {
        endDate = value;
        //Do Other tasks ......
        // Eg updateSomething();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can get in trouble when you call async methods in the setter.

Comment: So far you don't run an Task method. Then you get wrong executions' order

Comment: Worth pointing out that this answer uses the AspNetCore `InputDate` component. The question refers to using the HTML `input` element within Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the blazor elements for time :

```
<InputDate Type="InputDateType.Time" class="form-eliment jds-d-inline-block jds-max-width150" @bind-Value="model.RunAutomaticallyAt"> </InputDate>
```

Answer (score 0):

both Prevent default actions for events and Stop event propagation are supported  in Blazor apps since .NET Core 3.1 Preview 2 check thisd link 
[here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/11/04/apsnet-core-update.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To use blazor elements for time:

```
<InputDate Type="InputDateType.Time" 
class="form-eliment" @bind-Value="model.attribute"> </InputDate>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try using @bind-Value instead of just @bind, it works for me

```
        <div class="col-4 border border-primary border-0 text-left">
            <InputDate id="expenseedate" class="form-control form-control-sm col-4" format-value="yyyy-MM-dd" @bind-Value="@_endDate" @oninput="@ResetError" placeholder="Enter Expense end Date"></InputDate>
        </div>
```

Comment: Using `format-value="yyyy-MM-dd" ` doesn't have any effect, for me.